# I can't load text from file properly

Tags: c++, fstream

I can't seem to find what's wrong with this piece of code. It's a function that will load a couple of simple settings from a file. The problem is that the cout in the while loop doesn't show anything, only blank and an end line. It was put there for testing. Also the array "config_temp" only has blanks. I always used this method and even looked in previous projects and tutorials how it was written there. I can't find the expenation for this. Please help.

```
void load()
{
    string config_temp[5];//temporary array into which the config is loaded to
    int cc=1;//config counter
    int ac=0;//array counter

    ifstream file;
    string line;

    file.open("config.txt",ios::in);

    while(getline(file,line))
    {
        if(cc%2!=1)
        {
            cout<<line<<endl;
            config_temp[ac]=line;
            ac++;
        }
        cc++;
    }
    file.close();

    for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        cout<<config_temp[i]<<endl;
    }

    frames=sti(config_temp[0]);
    res_width=sti(config_temp[1]);
    res_height=sti(config_temp[2]);
    states=sti(config_temp[3]);
    frequency=sti(config_temp[4]);

    global_state=0;
}
```

Comment: did you check if the `while`-loop is even entered?

Comment: ...i.e. are you sure the file is even being opened?

Comment: i just checked with the good() function and it showed false. But the text file is a ordinary .txt. I just don't understand. So yeah, the file isn't even being opend.

Comment: The file must be in the working directory for this to work; note that this might not be the same dir as the executable itself and is a common pitfall for new programmers.

Comment: No, the file is in the same directory as the file that contains this function.

Comment: Your program must have permission to write and read files.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to specify `ios::in` when opening an `std::ifstream`.  The `std::ifstream` defaults to `ios::in`.